# iphone - iOS SDK 4.3.3, where can I find it?

Tags: iphone, sdk

My iphone is upgraded to iOS 4.3.3. Then I can't debug my app (xcode 4.0.2 and iOS SDK 4.3) on my iphone any more.

I have been trying to find iOS SDK 4.3.3 on apple's site, but it seems not there.

Any one can tell me where it is?

thanks

I went to the following site to look for.

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

by the way, in my xcode, I only have platform or iOS version 4.3, not 4.3.3 with current SDK

====More info:=====

in my xcode, if I try to run it on my device. It just say building successfully, then running, then finished running. no debug info in the console. just like nothing happened. on my iphone, my app is not installed.

my ipad is 4.3 (not upgraded to 4.3.3), app can be installed and run. I can also run on the iphone 4.3 simulator. just for my iphone and another colleaque's iphone (both 4.3.3), the app can't run. so i suspected it is my sdk version problem

The iphones with 4.3.3 are never jailbroken.

Comment: in my xcode, if I try to run it on my device. It just say building successfully, then running, then finished running. no debug info in the console. just like nothing happened. on my iphone, my app is not installed.

Comment: my ipad is 4.3, app can be installed and run. I can also run on the iphone 4.3 simulator. just for my iphone and another colleaque's iphone (both 4.3.3), the app can't run. so i suspected it is my sdk version problem

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken? This could probably lead to errors while developing.

Comment: @marzapower, no, the iphones belong to my company, not jailbroken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the latest stable release of Xcode is version 4.0.2. This version integrates all the iOS SDKs from 4.0 to 4.3, including also the iOS SDK 3.2 for iPad 1.

If you get errors while deploying, testing or debugging your app through Xcode, and the problem originates only on you device, I'd suggest to restore the latest iOS version on your iPhone through iTunes. When you're done, you can go back to Xcode and everything should work fine. Otherwise my best advice is to contact Apple Support directly to solve this issue.

By the way, you could also, as a temporary step do this:

1. Clean your project (cmd + shift + k)
2. Rebuild it
3. Remove the installed app from your device
4. Reboot it
5. Install the app through Xcode

At this point the problem should be solved. If not, proceed with the restoring of iOS.

Comment: yeah, i did the temporary step you said, it worked. now it is running. thanks

Answer (score 2):

xcode 4.0.2 and iOS SDK 4.3 is the latest release from apple... If you have a developer account You can download iOS 5 developer preview to work.

Comment: Thanks, I know now. But why my app can't be run on 4.3.3? for 4.3, it is fine.